# format date with ToString in powershell

Tags: powershell, datetime

```
$var1 = '06/10/2015 2:00 AM'
$var2 = ([DateTime]($var1)).addMinutes(15).ToString('mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm')
$var2
```

Current output - `15/10/2015 02:15`

but I want - `06/10/2015 02:15`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm'`. Note the uppercase 'M' for months. Lowercase 'm' is for minutes. These are the .NET custom time format strings documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Yes, and it's also likely the hours should either be `HH:mm`, or the am/pm designator should be added with `hh:mm tt`.